# GET Method not fetching latest data i POSTED Java and Spark

Tags: java, spark-java

So, this is the problem... when i insert new data to database using post method, it worked, the med table in database have new data. but when i fetch the data using GET Method, the data i inserted last time not showing.

i use spark for routing and rest client to test the endpoint. i've tried to render the data using react js but its the same, not rendering latest data.

this is the route :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        options("/*", (request, response) -> {

            String accessControlRequestHeaders = request.headers("Access-Control-Request-Headers");
            if (accessControlRequestHeaders != null) {
                response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", accessControlRequestHeaders);
            }

            String accessControlRequestMethod = request.headers("Access-Control-Request-Method");
            if (accessControlRequestMethod != null) {
                response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", accessControlRequestMethod);
            }

            return "OK";
        });

        // -- Check the authentication
        before((Filter) (req, res) -> {
            validateLogin(CommonUtils.getJsonConvertor(), req);

            res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE");
            res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token");
            res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

            System.out.println("API Endpoint accessed");
        });

        after((req, res) -> {
            res.type(Constants.STANDARD_RESPONSE_CONTENTTYPE);
        });

        // -- Handle the exceptions
        handleExceptions(CommonUtils.getJsonConvertor());

        new AuthController(CommonUtils.getJsonConvertor());
        new MedController(CommonUtils.getJsonConvertor());
    }
```

```
public void initializeController(final Gson jsonConverter) {
        get("/med", (req, res) -> {
            return getAll();
        }, CommonUtils.getJsonTransformer());

        get("/med/:id", (req, res) -> {
            return find(req);
        }, CommonUtils.getJsonTransformer());

        post("/med", (req, res) -> {
            return insert(jsonConverter, req, res);
        }, CommonUtils.getJsonTransformer());

        put("/med/:id", (req, res) -> {
            return update(jsonConverter, req, res);
        }, CommonUtils.getJsonTransformer());

        delete("/med/:id", (req, res) -> {
            return deleteById(req, res);
        }, CommonUtils.getJsonTransformer());
    }
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that after post-ing your new records are actually in your database?

Comment: yes, i've posting 10 records, and for each record, i check it eventualy... the data will show using GET Method again if i restart the program

Comment: Probably not Apache Spark related. Can you remove the tag?